# How to properly use clean URLs

Tags: clean-urls

I really want to learn how to use clean URLs but I'm unsure how it all works.  I have read a couple tutorials and watched some YouTube videos but they seemed very different from each other.  Is there a right/wrong way to do it?  Thanks.

Comment: It depends very much on your environment, including server (Apache, IIS, etc.), programming language, and framework (e.g. App Engine, ASP.NET MVC, etc.)

Comment: I've only worked with Apache and PHP

Answer (score 3):

An excellent post on A List-Apart:

- [How to Succeed With URLs](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/succeed/)